# Rails 3: uninitialized constant FactoryGirl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tdd, factory-bot

I am trying to create my first controller test using FactoryGirl for my Rails application, but I keep retrieving the following error:

```
uninitialized constant FactoryGirl
```

My Factories.rb file looks like this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :offer, class: "Offer" do |f|
    f.title     "Some title"
    f.description   "SomeDescription"
  end
end
```

And my controller test looks like this:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe OffersController do
 def valid_session
    {}
  end

  describe "GET index" do
     before { 
        @offer = FactoryGirl.create(:offer)
     }

    it "assigns all offers as @offers" do    
      get :index, {}, valid_session
      assigns(:offers).should eq([@offer])
    end
  end
end
```

My Gemfile looks like this:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'capybara', '1.1.2'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '>= 4.1.0', :require => false
end
```

What might I be missing since FactoryGirl isn't present?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You propably forgotten to require `factory_girl` in `spec_helper.rb`.

Comment: Such a simple mistake. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I suggest you to remove `:require => false`. Then you can use `FactoryGirl` also in `rails console` and can generate models using `rails generate factory_girl:model`.

Comment: when the gem 'factory_girl_rails' is install it also installs 'factory_girl' as a dependancy. So why must it be included in this file? Your suggestion worked for me, I'm just curious to know what the heck this is so! Thanks!